# Deleting /usr/share/icons folder and now icons are missing

Tags: gnome, 20.04

So I deleted the /usr/share/icons folder by accident and now certain icons are missing as well as the SHOW APPLICATIONS icon and top-right icons on my GNOME3 DE.

What do I do?

[image]

Comment: If you can get a copy of those icons from any other computer, you should try that.

Comment: Have you checked in your recycle folder if that are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check which packages have files in `/usr/share/icons` by running:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/icons
fontforge-common, gnome-sudoku, gnome-software-common, drumkv1-common, cheese-common, libkf5purpose-bin:amd64, libpeas-common, usb-creator-gtk, qemu-system-data, libgeocode-glib0:amd64, orca, modemmanager, rosegarden, gcr, aptdaemon-data, aisleriot, kipi-plugins-common, digikam-data, indicator-applet, imagemagick-6.q16, hugin-data, rygel, xjadeo, ubuntu-artwork, compton, transmission-common, thunderbird, gnome-power-manager, gnome-mahjongg, yelp, gnome-font-viewer, gnome-control-center-data, gnome-characters, cabextract, gnome-screenshot, gnome-mines, audacity-data, apport, software-properties-gtk, vlc-data, calf-plugins, indicator-printers, gnome-bluetooth, gnome-disk-utility, gnome-shell-common, eog, indicator-messages, xcursor-themes, ubuntu-web-launchers, gnome-todo-common, inkscape, ario-common, gnome-calculator, vim-common, indicator-session, unity-settings-daemon, poedit, gnome-online-accounts, rhythmbox-data, hicolor-icon-theme, blender-data, obs-studio, feh, gnome-calendar, totem-common, firefox, qdigidoc-tera, deja-dup, synaptic, update-notifier, nautilus-data, qsynth, qjackctl, vmpk, network-manager-gnome, file-roller, openshot-qt, yaru-theme-icon, oxygen-icon-theme, skypeforlinux, amsynth, dgedit, kdenlive-data, kdeconnect, gnome-system-monitor, gnome-logs, gmrun, xmonad, pianobooster, dmz-cursor-theme, minuet-data, baobab, wireshark-common, compizconfig-settings-manager, simple-scan, shotwell-common, seahorse, gnome-accessibility-themes, breeze-icon-theme, ibus-data, humanity-icon-theme, remmina-common, gedit-common, winetricks, virt-viewer, virt-manager, samplv1-common, fwupd, evince, flowblade, marble-qt-data, ubuntu-mono, adwaita-icon-theme, gnome-terminal, lmms-common, libreoffice-common, qdigidoc4, evolution-common, gimp-data, hydrogen-data, libkf5sane-data: /usr/share/icons
```

If you want the icons for a particular package back, you can re-install it. That will restore any missing files:

```
apt reinstall gimp-data
```

The only side-effect I can think of is that these packages will then be marked as manually installed and won't be later removed by `apt autoremove` if you've removed the package that caused them to be installed in the first place. I can't immediately see an option for disabling that though :(

If you want to reinstall all of the packages (which would make sense) you can use `sed` to get rid of the commas in `dpkg -S` output so it would be easier to copy-paste on to an `sudo apt reinstall` command line:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/icons | sed -e 's#,##g'
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you.